# NSData to UIImage quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I use `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: data]`, but the larger the size of the image by four times.Original **data.length=100 KB**, but this **image** now has more than 400 KB.You might say to complete with compression.But I'm than through the following method after compression **data.length=200 KB**.

**The following is my way**

*compression method*

```
 // spend is size (KB)
    - (NSData *)compressionImageData:(NSData *)data spend:(CGFloat)spend {

        if (data.length < spend) {
            return data;    //no compression
        }
        UIImage *sourceImg = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        CGFloat compression = 0.9f;
        CGFloat maxCompression = 0.1f;
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sourceImg, compression);

        while ([imageData length] > spend && compression > maxCompression) {
            compression -= 0.1;
            imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sourceImg, compression);
        }
        return imageData; 
    }
```

*Download the image method:*

```
- (void)loadPosterImage:(NSString *)imgURL {
    weakSelf();
    [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]
            options:SDWebImageDownloaderLowPriority
            progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {}
            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
                strongSelf();
                //  image is through [UIImage imageWithData: data]
                self.posterImage = image;
                self.posterData = data;

            }];
}
```

***The image size has more than 500 KB***

***data.lenght = 100KB***

This is the **data.length** of the image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzUvk.png]

This is the **image** of the image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozxa6.png]

Comment: Is there a way to put the data directly into the image size and data.length size

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: I want to get the "data. lenght= 100KB"  .Rather than a picture above 457 KB size Image

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why, but You can redraw the image like this:

```
+(NSData *)compressDataWithImage:(UIImage *)image toMaxFIleSize:(NSInteger)maxFileSize {
UIImage *comImage;

comImage = image;
CGFloat compression = 1.0;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(comImage, compression);
NSData *newData;
while (imageData.length > maxFileSize) {
    compression *= 0.5;
    newData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(comImage, compression);
    if (newData.length == imageData.length) {
        CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(comImage.size.width * 0.5, comImage.size.height * 0.5);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
        [comImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
        comImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        newData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(comImage, compression);
    }
    imageData = newData;
  }

return imageData;

}
```

Comment: @nvNoaDev 

You change the size of the image, you created a new "newSize".
I don't want image size

Comment: I'm sorry,this is the only way I known